# Bash for loop not completing with sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I would like to read in a template query and use bash to replace certain texts with key/value pairs I define in the script. Below is my code.

My bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A date_array


date_array[ly_end_date]="'2014-04-20'"
date_array[ly_4wks_beg_date]="'2014-03-24'"
date_array[ly_13wks_beg_date]="'2014-01-20'"
date_array[ly_52wks_beg_date]="'2013-04-21'"

date_array[ty_end_date]="'2015-03-22'"
date_array[ty_4wks_beg_date]="'2015-02-23'"
date_array[ty_13wks_beg_date]="'2014-12-22'"
date_array[ty_52wks_beg_date]="'2014-03-24'"

today=$(date +%F)

for f in ly_queries.template ty_queries.template; do
    filename="${f%.*}"

    for key in "${!date_array[@]}"; do
        value=${date_array[$key]}
        sed "s/${key}/${value}/g" "${f}" > "${filename}""-""${today}"".hql";
    done
done
```

My template file:

```
select foo
from bar
where date between ly_4wks_beg_date and ly_end_date;
```

Result:

```
select foo
from bar
where date between ly_4wks_beg_date and '2014-04-20';
```

My script completes, but only `ly_queries.template` file has the variable `ly_end_date` replaced with its associated value in the output. Could anyone provide me with some insights towards a solution? Thank you very much.

Bash version: GNU Bash 4.1.2

Sed version: GNU sed 4.2.1

System: RHEL 6.6 Santiago

Comment: Each time through your inner loop you start with the original file as the input file to `sed`.

Comment: Instead of replacing strings in the query, why don't you use user variables: `between @ly_4wks_beg_date and @ly_end_date`, and then put assignments to the variables before the `SELECT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your inner loop, you keep making the changes based on the original file, not the file as modified from the previous key. Instead of doing multiple `sed` commands, build up a single command with all the changes:

```
for f in ly_queries.template ty_queries.template; do
    filename="${f%.*}"
    changes=()

    for key in "${!date_array[@]}"; do
        value=${date_array[$key]}
        changes+=(-e "s/${key}/${value}/g")
    done
    sed "${changes[@]}" "${f}" > "${filename}-${today}.hql";
done
```